# How can I merge two pdf using pdfBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Hi there I am trying to generate pdf by combining two one from my local machine and another one from s3 I am not sure how to do this
here is what I tried doing -

```
S3Object object = amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, "name.pdf"));
InputStream ins = object.getObjectContent();
try {
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(ins);

    File file1 = new File(
            "C:\\Users\\admin\\example.pdf");
    PDFMergerUtility obj = new PDFMergerUtility();

    obj.setDestinationFileName(
            "C:\\Users\\admin\\newMerged.pdf");

    obj.addSource(file1);
    obj.addSource(String.valueOf(doc));
    obj.mergeDocuments();
    System.out.println("PDF Documents merged to a single file");
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error -  `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument@4d33940d (The system cannot find the file specified)`

I know this could not be the way, I wanna know how to do this thing.

Comment: welcome to SO , i added an answer if it satisfy your requirement please accept it as answer to improve the community .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use absolute pathname to where the file exists.

```
PDFMergerUtility result = new PDFMergerUtility();
result.addSource("C:\\...\\FileRead\\first.txt");
result.addSource("C:\\...\\FileRead\\second.txt");
result.setDestinationFileName("the destination path");
result.mergeDocuments();
```

Comment: I was concerned about   obj.addSource(String.valueOf(doc)); this line of code, as I am trying to put the file directly in source which is throwing that exception 
do you think that's ok?

Comment: @hafoxi2844 the exception as it says can not find you input pdf files, You need to give the absolute pathname to where the file exists.

Comment: Thanks for your time, one last thing can you tell me how can I do this without saving file locally in my system? All I want is to fetch pdf from s3 and merge it with the other that can also be at remote place is there any solution for this ?

Comment: As far as i remember the method signature of .addSource() not overloaded with distributed non local directories , so one practice perhaps will be downloading files then auto removing after merging in my humble opinion.